# Failed to retrieve NativeApplicationBuilder when running IBM MobileFirst 6.3 CLI

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We're trying to build our IBM MobileFirst project on version 6.3 via the command line and we always get a BUILD FAILED:
C:\Program Files\IBM\MobileFirst-CLI\mobilefirst-cli\node_modules\generator-worklight-server\lib\build.xml:341: Failed to retrieve NativeApplicationBuilder

What is NativeApplicationBuilder? Is it a Java thing, or something else?

Java Version being used is 1.7.0_80 64-Bit.

Comment: "Failed to retrieve" error message is not coming from MFP API.  This seems to be related to some native code.  Can you recreate this with a simple HelloWorld project?  Is this a hybrid project?  Which environment (Android, iOS, Windows Phone, etc) is included in your project?

Comment: The error ended up being because there was no common folder and we are running a hybrid app. Since we use a preprocessing script to build the common folder, it hadn't been run yet. Since there was no common folder, it looked for something native to build which didn't exist either. Therefore, we got the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error ended up being because there was no common folder and we are running a hybrid app. Since we use a preprocessing script to build the common folder, it hadn't been run yet. Since there was no common folder, it looked for something native to build which didn't exist either. Therefore, we got the error.

I should have looked closer into the build.xml file where it reported the error. It made sense after I saw that.